# How can we run a custom command / csproj Target before `dotnet run` and not during `dotnet test`

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj, dotnet-cli

is there a way to run a custom command before a `dotnet run` and not during `dotnet test`?
Currently, we have the following in our csproj

```xml
<Target BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

but that also runs with `dotnet test`.

I tried `BeforeTargets=Run` but that doesn't seem to work.

I know we could use env var (e.g. `Condition='$(SKIP_COMMAND)' != true`) but we'd like to have the command skipped by default (i.e. without having to set the env var manually or setting any `dotnet test` arguments) when running `dotnet test`.

Answer (score 1):

The `dotnet test` command always builds the project before the tests are executed, so the `BeforeBuild` target is always executed as well.

But there is a `--no-build` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#options) for `dotnet test` which disables the build. So if you build your project manually beforehand, you should be able to run the tests without rebuilding it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve our problem. 
`--no-build` is similar to `SKIP_COMMAND=true dotnet test`.. with the latter still building our project which is preferred.